# Does private methods are considered in the God Class code smell?

Tags: java, oop, pmd

The PMD started warn me about having the God Class after adding a small private method to an existing class.

I didn't find any clarification what types of methods are considered to be the reason of the code smell. It only says that it uses metrics to make a decision and such a class does too many things.

From my point of view we can have as many private methods as we want as long as we follow the Single Responsibility rule.

So I wanted to know whether my assumption is right or should I obey the PMD warning and make a refactoring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the very good GhostCat answer, I would add that
the God object pattern doesn't apply only for methods or even public methods.
It's an anti-pattern where the object (or class as the issue comes from `static` members) knows too much (fields) and or does too much (methods).

So fields and methods (`public` as `private`) accumulation in a same class may contribute to make a class or an object a undesirable god.

> From my point of view we can have as many private methods as we want
>   as long as we follow the Single Responsibility rule.

Single Responsibility principle for API is a really good thing.
But it doesn't mean that private processing/fields should violate this one.
 
Indeed as a class becomes really "big", the cohesion between its members may become low  and so an undesirable coupling between some members may appear.
So separating distinct processings in other classes makes sense to improve code readability and maintainability .

Answer (score 2):

I think you named the crucial concept: the single responsibility principle. And as long as you keep this concept in mind (and you follow the other SOLID rules) you should be fine.

I rather find a high number of private methods could be a good thing - as you are hopefully upholding the single layer of abstraction principle!

Of course: when there are really too many private methods it might be worth looking if there are certain "sub aspects" worth moving into distinct classes of their own.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that when you see that your class has too many private methods, often times this functionality can be extracted to another class and by doing so you can:

1. reduce duplication in your code base
2. improve its testability

So this rule is legitimate, because even if you think that your design is SOLID enough, many times your object composition could be in fact more crystalic.